# How to add custom tab button with external link?

Tags: tabs, customization, mediawiki

Using Mediawiki 1.19 and want to add tabs with external links right next to the tab buttons 'Page' and 'Discussion'. How to do it?

- Extension:DynamicTabs does not work because it has trouble with vector skins.
- Steps in [FAQ: How do I add/remove tabs throughout my wiki?](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFAQ#How_do_I_add.2Fremove_tabs_throughout_my_wiki.3F) do not have any effect at all.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the FAQ was outdated. For newer versions of MediaWiki, you have to use the [SkinTemplateNavigation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinTemplateNavigation) hook instead of the [SkinTemplateContentActions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinTemplateContentActions) hook.  I updated [the FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFAQ#How_do_I_add.2Fremove_tabs_throughout_my_wiki.3F).  Basically, you need to do something like this:

```
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateNavigation'][] = 'replaceTabs';
function replaceTabs( $skin, &$links) {  
        $links['namespaces']['name_of_tab'] = array(
                'class' => false or 'selected', // if the tab should be highlighted
                'text' => 'text_of_tab', // what the tab says
                'href' => 'url_to_point_to', // where it links to
                'context' => 'main',
        );
        return true;
}
```

Comment: From what I understand this can only be used to replace a tab with an external link and not to add a completely new tab pointing to an external url like the OP asked. Is this correct?

Comment: No I'm pretty sure you can add new tabs with it. I'm using it to add a new tab in MediaWiki 1.17.