# Add tab and open in new window/tab

Tags: php, tabs, customization, mediawiki

I´ve searched for a possibillity to add tabs next to Page and Discussion and found below.
[Link to the post with the below code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192641/how-to-add-custom-tab-button-with-external-link/15895055#15895055)

```
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateNavigation'][] = 'replaceTabs';
function replaceTabs( $skin, &$links) {  
    $links['namespaces']['name_of_tab'] = array(
            'class' => false or 'selected', // if the tab should be highlighted
            'text' => 'text_of_tab', // what the tab says
            'href' => 'url_to_point_to', // where it links to
            'context' => 'main',
    );
    return true;
}
```

It works great but the windows are opened in the same window.
I have added the `$wgExternalLinkTarget = '_blank';` but it seems to not working with these link (works for the other external links i´m currently have on my wiki).

Is there a way to force the tab links to open in new window or tab?

*I am using:*
*MediaWiki version: 1.19.1*
*PHP: 5.3.6 (apache2handler)*
*MySQL: 5.5.16*

Comment: Anyone got some idea?

Comment: I found a Hook that probably will do what I ask for but I do not know how to implement it. **`$wgHooks['LinkerMakeExternalLink']`**. Anyone that may be able to help me?

Comment: No one that could assist me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without modifying the PHP code for the skin you're using (e.g. [`skins/Vector.php`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/skins/Vector.php) for the Vector skin).  If you do want to do that, the code to render the navigation tabs is, surprisingly enough, in the `renderNavigation()` method.  Or you could just modify the `key` string (normally used to inject `title` and `accesskey` attributes into the link) for your tab after it has been set in `execute()`.

If you don't like the idea of hacking your skin, an easier solution might be to use JavaScript.  Something like the following code (with `name_of_tab` replaced with the name of your custom tab) in your [site JavaScript](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/JavaScript) ought to do it:

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    // run this code after page has loaded:
    $( '#ca-name_of_tab a' ).attr( 'target', '_blank' );
} );
```

Of course, this will do nothing for users with JavaScript disabled.  There's also a tiny window where someone might be able to click the link after it has loaded but before the JavaScript has had a chance to run.

It's possible, in principle, to avoid the last issue by hiding the tab with CSS until the JS code runs.  However, making sure that the tab *always* starts out initially hidden, but *only* if JS is enabled, *without* hacking the skin, regardless of whether MediaWiki is configured to do async script loading, gets... surprisingly tricky.  In fact, I gave up on trying to figure it out.  Maybe writing a custom ResourceLoader module might do it, but I've spent way too much time on this already.